# Vue Component do not render slots content after deployment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs-slots

I do have a problem with Vue slots.
If I start the local project with `npm run dev` the content of the slots is populated.
However, when I deploy the project, the two slots are empty.

Why are the slot contents not loaded as soon as I deploy the project?

#### SLOTS

[image]

#### DOM (locally and deployed)

[image]

Output of `npm list vue`:

```
nuxt@2.14.7
@nuxt/builder@2.14.7
@nuxt/vue-app@2.14.7
vue@2.6.12  deduped
@nuxt/core@2.14.7
@nuxt/vue-renderer@2.14.7
vue@2.6.12  deduped
vue-carousel-3d@1.0.1
vue@2.6.12
```

Comment: We will probably need more details since here, it's coming from the env. Do you have env variables that may not be set on production ? Also, can you share your `nuxt.config.js` and your `package.json` (edit your question with those) please ? Lastly, prefer posting text rather than code images, it's always preferred here.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by replacing the tag slot with a component. The slot tag is obsolete in Vue 2.x.

Comment: Haha, didn't even saw this one, indeed the syntax is `<template #navbar></template>` now ! :D